# Many-to-one bidirectional relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm begininng with Rails and I'm getting kind of confused with the relations.
The problem is quite simple, I have a `Station` class representing a train station, and a `Shop` class. I'd simply want the shop to have a station, representing the closest train station, so I guess it would be a many-to-one relation.

Without any ORM I'd just add a foreign key of the station in the shop table. After looking up about rails relations, I ended up with

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :station
end

class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :shop
end
```

As properly speaking, the shop does not really BELONG to a station I'm finding this kind of strange, so I'd like to know if this is the right way to proceed or if I'm getting confused.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, if a shop can be connected to only one (closest) station it is nothing strange in saying that it "belongs" to it. Not in ordinary sense of course but in object relationship

Comment: Mm, actually by writing ``belongs_to`` I kind of have the feeling that if a station were to be destroyed it would (or at least could) cascade to the shop, which kind of does not really make sense.
Anyway if this is the right way I guess it is just that I am not yet used to it.

Comment: There is a `:dependent` option for this (in `has_many` association). `:nullify` value for this option will preserve Shops even if their Station is destroyed (nullifying the foreign key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way to proceed. "Belongs to" simply means "has a foreign key to" - it doesn't necessarily mean that this is a sensible way of describing the relationship in real terms.

As posted, the code won't quite work - you need to pluralize the has_many side; i.e.:

```
class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :shops
end
```

You can test the relationship actually works by firing up the rails console ('rails c') from your application folder and the experimenting with creating objects. Assuming you've created the corresponding tables, you should be able to do things like:

```
station = Station.create
shop = Shop.create
shop.station = station
station.shops
station.shops.build
```

...etc

Comment: Ok, I guess I was kind of confused with the name 'belongs_to' but I think I got it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`belongs_to` and `has_many` do not describe either the ownership or the scope or the life cycles for the objects they relate. They just describe the references (the keys) between the objects.

Such references can have their life cycle tied with :dependent, :autosave, etc. options.
Other options such as :read_only reduce privileges of edition from reference to another.

Ownership is a concept that you have to define yourself. For instance: a Post in a forum can "belong" to different users with different privileges. Who is the owner? The admin? The last editor? The one that created the post? For such behaviors, extra definition and mechanics are needed. I recommand you take a look at the CanCan gem for this ( https://github.com/ryanb/cancan ).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Okay I'm going to look a bit further at the dependent and autosave stuff!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :shops, :dependent => "nullify"
end
```

if your station gets deleted still the shops will be their